# XML Digital Signature in .NET

Tags: .net, digital-signature

I would Like to know which type of certificate do I need to get from a Certification Authority to Sign an XML Document in .NET ?

We have a xml eletronic invoice that we need to sign using a Digital Certificate.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you only need a certificate with has sign purpose. You can import it in the certificates store of Windows to use it directly.

After that, you can use it to sign using one of the many libraries available. For example:

- In Java, the signature applet created by the Jaume I University (CryptoApplet), that you can find at projectestic.uji.es/pr/cryptoapplet
- In .NET: a new project I'm involved in (XAdES .NET Project), that you can find at xadesnet.codeplex.com

Regards

Comment: Libraries are unnecessary. Look at the [SignedXml class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.aspx) and related classes.

Comment: That's right, libraries are unnecessary. They just make life easier. Except if you want to sign invoices using eFactura format, for example, or XAdES. Then you will have to use one library.